# English Production Rules

Tags: grammar, rules

Does an official set of production rules (formal grammar) for English exist? Something along the lines of:

```
Sentence -> Clause EndPunctuation
Clause -> Subject Predicate
Subject -> NounPhrase
NounPhrase -> Determiner Noun
            | Adjective Noun
EndPunctuation -> EndPunctuation EndPunctuation
                | .
                | !
                | ?
```

If so, where can it be found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  (I don't know what "official" would mean, here.)  The closest thing I know to that is the book GPSG ([see Generalized Phrase Structure Grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_phrase_structure_grammar)), which however does not claim to give a comprehensive account of English, and would not give a practical parser. It would have to be supplemented with a lexicon.  It is a context free phrase structure grammar for a part of English, though.